# qsort record(char array) in descending order

Tags: c, sorting, arrays, qsort

I'm trying to print and sort my dynamic memory of records in descending order using qsort. I'm using the command-line to determine how the records should be sorted.

Code for printing out the records:

```
void print_records_by_name(record_list *list, int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    size_t i;

    if (argc == 2) {
        if (strcmp(argv[1], "+n") == 0) {
            qsort(list->data, list->nused, sizeof(record), sort_name_asc);
        } else if (strcmp(argv[1], "-n") == 0) {
            qsort(list->data, list->nused, sizeof(record), sort_name_des);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < list->nused; i++) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s %s %d\n", list->data[i].name.last, list->data[i].name.first, list->data[i].score);
    }
}
```

I have the code for sorting it ascending:

```
int sort_name_asc(const void *p, const void *q)
{
    const record *pp = p;
    const record *qq = q;
    int n1, n2;

    n1 = strcmp(pp->name.first, qq->name.first);
    n2 = strcmp(pp->name.last, qq->name.last);

    if (n2 == 0) {
        return n1;
    }

    return n2;
}
```

This is what I have for descending order:

```
int sort_name_des(const void *p, const void *q)
{
    const record *pp = p;
    const record *qq = q;
    int n1, n2;

    n1 = strcmp(qq->name.first, pp->name.first); /*just switched the pp and qq*/
    n2 = strcmp(qq->name.last, pp->name.last); /*just switched pp and qq*/

    if (n2 != 0) {
        return n1;
    }

    return n2;
}
```

I compiled it and it doesn't work, any ideas how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: _I'm pretty sure this doesn't work_.  You are not sure?  Why are you not sure?

Comment: *"I'm pretty sure this doesn't work"*. Would you care to elaborate, or is this supossed to be a guessing-game?

Comment: I compiled it and it doesn't print it out neither descending and sorted

Comment: Look at the outputs of the `strcmp()` function, that will get you far down the road to what mods need to be made, and solving this...

Comment: `qsort(list->data, list->nused, sizeof(record), sort_name_des);` this line does not look right.  Is list->data an array of things, or just a single item?

Comment: it is from a dynamic memory, so it would be in and array of things

Comment: Well, that is kind of like saying "it came from outside, so it will be purple".   What does coming from dynamic memory have to do with what type of data it is?  Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @user2122151 - I am still not sure _exactly_ you are asking, or what your data looks like, but in the middle of it all, you seem to be asking how to sort an array of strings, in both ascending and descending order.  I put a small example below to see if that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

***Since I do not*** know what `record_list *list` looks like,  that is:

I am not sure that the statement `qsort(list->data, list->nused, sizeof(record), sort_name_asc);` is correct, that `list->data` is really an array, or that `list->used` is really the number of items in the array,...

***So, I will simply*** illustrate a string compare in ascending and descending order, and hope that helps you:

***Note: compare functions*** are identical with the exception of the return value...

```
#include <ansi_c.h>

static int sortstringAscending( const void *str1, const void *str2 );
static int sortstringDescending( const void *str1, const void *str2 );

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char string1[10][4] = {"eee","bbb","jjj","ddd","aaa","fff","ggg","iii","hhh","ccc"};

    //Important that you populate the qsort function with the right values
    //that is qsort(StringArray, numElemetsInArray, sizeOfEachElement, sortFunction);

    qsort(string1, 10, 4,sortstringAscending);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) printf("string %d is: %s\n", i, string1[i]);
    printf("\n");
    qsort(string1, 10, 4,sortstringDescending); 
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) printf("string %d is: %s\n", i, string1[i]);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}

static int sortstringAscending( const void *str1, const void *str2 )
{
    const char *rec1 = (const char *)str1;
    const char *rec2 = (const char *)str2;
    int val = strcmp(rec1, rec2);

    return val;
}

static int sortstringDescending( const void *str1, const void *str2 )
{
    const char *rec1 = (const char *)str1;
    const char *rec2 = (const char *)str2;
    int val = strcmp(rec1, rec2);

    return -1*val;//Because of the way strcmp() works, 
                  //this simple change causes the results 
                  //to be reversed for a string array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you swutched the pointers in the second function, you need to keep the same logic.

```
if (n2 == 0) {
    return n1;
}
```

Or simply:

```
int sort_name_des(const void *p, const void *q)
{
    return -sort_name_asc(p, q);
}
```